# Implementation of browsers in mobile devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, v8, spidermonkey

I have been looking at Chrome and Firefox these days. On a desktop platform the V8 and the SpiderMonkey respectively are being used by them to compile and run the Javascript but how does it happen on mobile devices(android and iOS).

My major question is that is it the same engine as it is in desktop browsers or is it a minified version?
Also, if it the same how is the same performance optimisation achieved?

Comment: questions on StackOverflow should state a problem. You them to not have a problem, but want to know how something works. I think your question is offtopic because it is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 runs on ~10 different CPU architectures and is used unchanged across all platforms that Chrome runs on (except iOS, because Apple doesn't allow jitting).